# drag and drop angular without jquery

Tags: angularjs

My drag and drop is not working. Can anyone tell me what wrong in it?

html link:

```
<head>
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="components/angular-dragdrop/src/angular-dragdrop.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body  ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="btn btn-primary" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list1" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}" ng-hide="!list1.title">{{list1.title}}
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options ng-model="list2" jqyoui-droppable style='height:100px; margin-top:40px;border-color:green;'>
        <div class="btn btn-success" data-drag="false" data-jqyoui-options ng-model="list2" jqyoui-draggable ng-hide="!list2.title">{{list2.title}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Angular code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.list1 = {title: 'AngularJS - Drag Me'};
  $scope.list2 = {};    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Register the angular-drag-and-drop module in your app:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", ['ang-drag-drop']);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.list1 = {title: 'AngularJS - Drag Me'};
  $scope.list2 = {};

});
```

Comment: Give us more information what's not working? Did you checked the console logs? Are you receiving errors?

Comment: the button I created is not dragging anywhere

Answer (score -1):

I came across three show-stoppers when I tried to make this work:

1. First, verify that the path to the component actually exists. On my machine, at least, Bower installs to `./bower_components/`, not `./components/`.
2. [Simo Endre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265592/466226) is right that the component needs to be registered, but it needs to be registered as `ngDragDrop`, not `ang-drag-drop`.
3. Finally, the component in question ([codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop)) relies on jQuery and jQuery-UI to do its magic, so you'll need to add them to your project:

   ```
   <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     ...
   </head>
   ```

Not sure if this last one is a deal-breaker for you, given the title of your question. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Anyway, after making those changes the code seems to work as intended.

Comment: Downvote for not having actually read the question. It says specifically "without jquery".